# How do I 'securely' download pip on Windows 7?

Tags: django, pip

I want to install pip on Windows 7. On http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html#id6 it says that 'securely' download it. Not sure what does it mean. When I click on get-pip.py I am directed to a page https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py with loads of binary data.

Comment: https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py is a plain text file. how could you get loads of binary data?

Comment: I am not able to see any download link of the file. Anything that I am missing here?

Comment: That's the raw file, you don't need a download link. Your browser has a Save As menu option, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to install pip on Windows 7.

First, make sure you have installed an official supported version of Python; the most reliable way to do this is to install from the official [windows installer page](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/).

Next, navigate to [this page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and then search for `pip` and you will see Windows installer packages for different versions of pip that correspond to different versions of Python. Download the one that matches the version of Python you have installed.

Once the package is downloaded, double click it to install it just like any other Windows application.

Answer (score 0):

https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py is not a download page. It's a installation file. The doc is quite clear about that.

> To install or upgrade pip, securely download get-pip.py. [1]
>
> **Then run the following** (which may require administrator access):
>
> python get-pip.py